Why do I have EVI values out of the range?
I'm using Landsat 5 and 8 images to calculate EVI in Google Earth Engine. For what I read, the range of EVI is between -1 and +1 but I get values higher than +1 in all the EVI images. I need to understand why because I can found any source where this situation is explained. This the script I used for Landsat 5:

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_TOA");

var data = ee.Image(dataset
           .filterDate('1984-01-01','1984-12-31')
           .filterBounds(Itabo)
           .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
           .first());
print(data);

var FCC ={bands: ['B4','B3','B1'], min: '0', max: '0.3'};
Map.addLayer(data,FCC, 'Landsat5');


var evi = data.expression(
          '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))' , {
            'NIR' : data.select('B4'),
            'RED' : data.select('B3'),
            'BLUE' : data.select('B1')
});
print(evi);
Map.addLayer(evi, {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['FF0000', '00FF00']}, 'EVI');

Export.image.toDrive ({
          image:evi,
          scale:5,
          region:Itabo})


You should try looking at your results in Google Earth Engine. Use the Inspector Panel to check the EVI of your image at any location. I ran the same code and checked the result and the EVI was within the range of -1 and +1. Maybe the error arises when you load the image in ArcMap.

Hi! Thank you for you anwser. I tried loading the image to QGIS and it worked :D

During the calibration process, the reflectance/radiance of some bands (especially the blue band) can sometimes be reported as negative, or it can be saturated (above 100%).  That'll make many formulas blow up.
You should:

apply the scaling factors listed in the dataset description so you have actual reflectance/radiance numbers.  (TOA is radiance; consider using L2)
and
Mask any pixels that are out of range (less than 0, greater than 1).


Noel summarizes the main factors. Also, you should consider that old images have some noise. For instance:

Selecting a noisy pixel, I got these values:
Blue: 0.2661
Red: 0.14071
NIR: 0.21266
With these values, the EVI index is 2.93, far higher than expected. But it's only noise, so these pixels shouldn't be considered valid. There many ways to remove noise, although you can lose resolution with some approaches.
